# Rigorous meaning of conditional expectation in Feynman-Kac formula/in general

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation, stochastic-analysis

In Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula and plenty of other books/sources, Feynman-Kac formula is expressed in a form of the type
$$f(t,x)=E(f(T,X_T)\mid X_t=x)$$ What is the rigorous meaning this conditional expectation conditioned on $X_T = x$ for $X_T$ with continuous distribution? Is there a definition or is it notation for something else?

In elementary courses one defines things like $E(Y\mid X=x)$ as $$ E(Y\mid X=x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}yf_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) \, dy$$ but this definition assumes that for $(X,Y)$ there exists a joint pdf $f_{XY}$ and also that we fix a version of this pdf. It is not clear (at least to me) that changing this pdf on a set of measure $0$ will yield the same result for $E(Y\mid X=x)$.

Comment: Your explanations point eloquently at the reasons why this cannot be a satisfying definition. Rather, for every integrable $Y$, one defines $E(Y\mid X)$ as any integrable random variable $Z$ such that 1. $Z$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable and 2. $E(Z\mathbf 1_B)=E(Y\mathbf 1_B)$ for every $B$ in $\sigma(X)$. It happens that this defines $E(Y\mid X)$ up to null sets in the sense that if $Z$ and $Z'$ make 1. and 2. hold then $P(Z=Z')=1$. Additionally, 1. can be replaced by the condition that $Z=u(Y)$ for some measurable $u$ and 2. by the condition that $E(Zv(X))=E(Yv(X))$ for every measurable ...

Comment: ... bounded function $v$. In your case, for every $t$, there exists some function $v_t$ (depending on $T$ and $f$) such that $E(f(T,X_T)\mid X_t)=v_t(X_t)$ almost surely. Feynman-Kac formula asserts that, up to null $x$-sets, the function $f$ solves $f(t,x)=v_t(x).$

Comment: Thank you very much Did! I failed to mention I am familiar with the rigurous definition of conditional expectation (with respect to any sigma algebra). I was under the impression there was something more to it in this case and I think I have found what I was looking for in Karatzas-Shreve, "Brownian motion and stochastic calculus" pages 73 and 268. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Karatzas-Shreve, "Brownian motion and stochastic calculus" pages 73 and 268 lies one possible answer. They prove the existence not only of the Brownian Motion but also of what they call a "Brownian family" which is the filtered space, the process, and a familily of probabilities $(P^x)_{x\in\mathbb{R^d}}$ such that for each $P^x$ the process is a Brownian motion starting at $x$ with probability $1$ (and there's also a certain measurability condition relating this probabilities) .

Then, in the case where the process $X$ is a Brownian Motion, the meaning of the expression $f(t,x)=E(f(T,X_T)∣X_t=x)$ is actually $$f(t,x)=E^{P^x}(f(T,X_{T-t}))$$ rather than "an actual conditional expectation". And the idea would be the same for other Ito processes $X$.

Comment: I guess you actually mean $$f(t,x)=E^{x}(f(T,X_{T-t}))$$ Also, the construction you allude to can be greatly simplified if one notes that $X$ under $P^x$ is distributed as $x+X$ under $P^0$.

Comment: See also [this quesion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922714/definition-of-conditional-expectation-of-y-given-x/1928218#1928218).

Comment: @Gordon: thank you! But now I wonder: Is the interpretation given in the answer (with the family probabilities $P^x$) equivalent to the one you mention using a formalization of conditional probabilty? How about the following third interpretation: We assume there exists a family of Ito processes $(X^{t,x}(u))_{t,x}$ such that $X^{t,x}(t)=x$ and $E(f(T,X_T|X_t=x)$ is simply $E(f(T,X^{t,x}(T))$. Are they all equally rigurous?

Comment: @Gordon I wrote your name incorrectly before

Comment: No problem @webbster. Your question makes sense. We can think about how to unify them.