# Definition of Conditional expectation of Y given X.

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $(S,F,P)$ be probability space.

Let $X,Y$ be continuous random variables from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}.$

Formal Definition of Conditional Expectation $E(Y|X)$ of $Y$ to X is

$\sigma{(X)} - Borel$ measurable function such that 
$$ \int_A E(Y|X) dP = \int_A Y dP$$

for all $A \in \sigma(X)$ where $\sigma(X)$ is sigma algebra generated $\{X^{-1}(B) :$ $B$ is borel set$\}$

What is the definition of $E(Y|X=x)$ ?

Comment: It can be shown that a Borel-measurable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ exists such that $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)=f(X)$. Based on that $\mathbb E(Y\mid X=x)$ can be identified with $f(x)$. Unfortunately $f$ is in general not unique, so it is still a dubious definition.

Comment: It is $\int_{\{\omega|X(\omega)=x\}}YdP$

Comment: @kolobokish No, it is not. If e.g. $X$ has continuous distribution then  $P(\{\omega\mid X(\omega)=x\})=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$ and consequently $\int_{\{\omega\mid X(\omega)=x\}}YdP=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$. $\frac{\int_{\{\omega\mid X(\omega)=x\}}YdP}{P(\{\omega\mid X(\omega)=x\})}$ would be better, because it works if $X$ has discrete distribution.

Comment: Ah, yes i'm sorry. I meant $\frac{1}{P(\{\omega|X(\omega)=x\})}\int_{\{\omega|X(\omega)=x\}}YdP$. Though it is not well-defined.

Comment: @kolobokish Then why bring this to the fore, especially since the OP specified that X is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can also define $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)$ through the factorization lemma: Since $Z = \mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, there is some measurable $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is unique on $X(\Omega)$ such that $Z = g\circ X$. Now we can define $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x) = g(x)$. Note that this depends on the version $Z$ of $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ that one takes.

Answer (score 1):

This is defined in many probability books, for example, see [Shiryaev](https://www.amazon.ca/Probability-Albert-N-Shiryaev-1995-12-08/dp/B01JPR2AOW). Specifically, \begin{align*}
m(x) \equiv E(Y \mid X=x)
\end{align*} 
is a Borel measurable function such that, for any Borel measurable set $A$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\{X \in A\}} Y dP &= \int_A m(x) P_{X}(dx),
\end{align*}
where $P_X(dx)$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure generated by the distribution function of $X$, that is, for any Borel measurable set $B$,
\begin{align*}
P_X(B) = P(X \in B).
\end{align*}
It can also be shown that (see Page 196 of [Shiryaev](https://www.amazon.ca/Probability-Albert-N-Shiryaev-1995-12-08/dp/B01JPR2AOW)),
\begin{align*}
\int_A m(x) P_{X}(dx) = \int_{\{X \in A\}} m(X) dP.
\end{align*}
In other words,
\begin{align*}
m(X) = E( Y \mid X).
\end{align*}