# Conditional probability on zero probability events (Definition)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega ,{\mathcal {F}},P)$ be a probability space, $X$ is a $(M,{\mathcal {M}})$-value random variable, $Y$ is a $(N,{\mathcal {N}})$-value random variable, and $f$ is a measurable function from $M \mapsto N$.
We **don't** know about the existence of the joint probability density of $(X, f(X))$. Is $P(X \in E \vert f(X)=y)$ well-defined? In otherwords, does this limit exist or not: $\lim_{r \mapsto 0} P(X \in E \vert f(X) \in (y-r, y+r))$?

This question is about the definition of conditional probability on zero probability events. Even if, it is well-defined, the application of the definition is not clear to me. I asked a question about the application of conditional probability on zero probability events [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943821/conditional-probability-on-zero-probability-events-application).

Comment: The event $f(X)=y$ might have positive probability, so is not necessarily a problem. However if we have an event $A$ of probability zero, a conditional probability $P(B|A)=P(B\cap A)/P(A)$ is not defined. We might say that there is no "good" definition: We can read $P(B|A)=x$ as "assuming $A$ happened, the chance of $B$ happening is $x$". If $P(A)=0$ then $A$ never happens, so we are starting with a false premise which implies anything.

Comment: By convention $P(X\in E\mid Y=y)=u(y)$ where $u$ is any measurable function such that $P(X\in E\mid Y)=u(Y)$ almost surely. Thus, if $P(Y=y)=0$, $u(y)$ can literally assume any value.

Comment: I find odd that an answer explaining the case when $(X,Y)$ has a density satisfies you although $(X,f(X))$ never has a density. Be aware that there exists a general formula for $P(X\in A\mid f(X))$, at least when $f$ is smooth.

Comment: @Did No, it didn't satisfy me because I wanted to know about the definition of conditional probability when we don't know about the existence of the joint density. The fact that if $f$ is measurable, then we can define the conditional probability was what I meant.

Comment: "No, it didn't satisfy me" Thus you closed the page by accepting an answer merely 6 hours after it was posted? O well...

Comment: @Did That's was my mistake. I shouldn't have accepted an answer before making sure that it is correct. But, I explicitly asked my question and the responder said yes to it with an answer. I am still thinking about the suggested answer, but as I said checking the correctness of the answer is hard for me. So, if you have any idea about the proposed answer, I appreciate if you bring them up.

Comment: Sorry but checking the answer below, which is almost entirely offtopic ("almost" because what the OP does in the remaining parts is unclear to me), does not interest me.

Comment: The revamped answer below makes for a rather fascinating read... Re its relevance though, I am under the impression that it does not even start to address your question in cases such as $f(x)=\max(x,0)$... // Did you try to check the rigorous definition of $E(U\mid V)$ for any random variables $U$ and $V$, $U$ being integrable? Once you master it, you could simply plug in $U=\mathbf 1_{X\in E}$ and $V=f(X)$ in it to solve your question.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: If we reformulate the equation to $P(A)\cdot P(B|A) = P(A)$, then that equation gives no reason why $P(B|A)$ could not be defined;  it just cannot be derived from $P(A)$ and $P(A\cap B)$. There's of course still the question whether there can be a consistent definition of $P(B|A)$ in that case, but that question cannot be answered by looking at that equation alone. If you take that equation as definition, then what this amounts to is whether that definition can be *consistently extended* to the case $P(A)=P(A\cup B)=0$.

Comment: Note also that for infinite spaces, $P(A)=0$ does *not* mean that $A$ never happens. For example, imagine getting a random number from the interval $[0,1]$ under uniform distribution. You are *guaranteed* that whatever number you get, the probability to get that number was $0$.

Comment: I guess [this wikipedia article on *regular conditional probability*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability) may interest you.

Comment: See also the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922714/definition-of-conditional-expectation-of-y-given-x/1928218#1928218).

Comment: It's always best to ask the main question, not the question you came to while attempting a solution. (You can include that as extra information.) See this on the x-y problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: The application that you have added is a new question. You should restore this post to the original question, which I have answered fully, completely and with all the generality that you required, and start a new post for your new question.

Comment: @EvanAad Can you take a look at the new question I asked? I wrote a solution based on this topic.

Comment: @EvanAad "one of the five people who upvoted my answer read it, understood it, and, by upvoting, sanctioned it as valid. " The trust this places on the meaningfulness of votes on the site is either touching or self-serving or both. The pressure you put on the OP to accept your answer although it is offtopic and they probably do not understand it, is not touching.

Comment: @EvanAad You flatter yourself too much ("bitter"? huh?). The chaotic evolution of the page is testimony that something went astray. And yes, I find unsavory the moves to make the OP accept one's answer.

Comment: @Did: You know well that OP accepted my answer a couple days ago, all on their own, except you pressured them to retract it. "unsavory moves" you say?

Comment: @EvanAad Wow. You really made this thread degenerate into something slightly disgusting. Sorry if I leave now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***The short answer***

1. Yes, if $N=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{N}$ is the Borel field, then, for every $A \in \mathcal{M}$, the limit $\lim_{\Delta y \mapsto 0} P(X \in A\ |\ Y \in (y-\Delta y, y+\Delta y))$ exists $P_Y$-almost surely, and this is true whether or not $Y = f(X)$, and whether or not $X,Y$ have a joint density. (This is the content of Theorem 9(1) below.)
2. Furthermore, the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ obtained by setting $f(y) := \lim_{\Delta y \mapsto 0} P(X \in A\ |\ Y \in (y-\Delta y, y+\Delta y))$ wherever possible, and, say, $f(y):=0$ elsewhere, is consistent with the traditional measure-theoretic definition of $P(X\in A\ |\ Y=y)$, given by \eqref{CondProb}. (This is the content of Corollary 17(1).)

The proof of these facts is a consequence of theorems 1.29 ("Differentiating measures") and 1.30 ("Differentiation of Radon measures") in reference [3] (a shout-out to user [Del](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/366527/del), who [pointed me to this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940544/a-measure-theoretic-analogue-to-the-concept-of-derivative)). It makes use of the concept of the derivative of an outer measure w.r.t another outer measure.

I will devote the rest of this answer to carefully derive facts 1 and 2 stated above. As far as I know, this is the first time this fundamental, intuitive result, which is often claimed (for instance, on p. 157 of [4], p. 136 of [1]), is proved. I'll be grateful (if somewhat disappointed) to anyone who can cite a precedence.

---

***Example***

Before embarking on a formal proof, let's see how the results of the next section can be used to introduce the concept of "probability conditioned on a non-discrete random variable" in a way that is simultaneously intuitive and mathematically sound.

Consider, for instance, the following excerpt taken from a popular undergraduate textbook ([6] example 5e, p. 255).

> Consider $n + m$ trials having a common probability of success. Suppose, however, that this success probability is not fixed in advance but is chosen from a uniform $(0,1)$ population.

Letting $N$ denote the number of successes, and letting $X$ denote the probability that a given trial is a success, this excerpt gives natural rise to the concept of conditional probability, but when we attempt to parlay our intuition into formulas, we discover that an expression of the form $P(N = n\ |\ X=x)$ is not well-defined as per the familiar formula $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, since $P(X=x)=0$.

Intuition suggests to overcome this obstacle by defining
$$
P(N=n\ |\ X=x) = \lim_{\Delta x\downarrow 0} \frac{P(N=n, x - \Delta x < X < x + \Delta x)}{P(x - \Delta x < X < x + \Delta x)},
$$
provided the limit exists. Theorem 9(1) assures us that the limit indeed exists almost everywhere. Theorem 17(1) implies that if we so define $P(N=n\ |\ X=x)$ wherever possible, we will obtain a function that is a conditional probability in the traditional measure-theoretic sense (described in the next paragraph), hence we may soundly subject it to the usual manipulations involving conditional probabilities, such as the law of total probability. Note that in this example the joint random variable $(N,X)$ does not have a joint density (more precisely no joint density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Now scratch everything we have discussed so far, and suppose we start by defining the conditional probability $P(X\in A\ |\ Y=y)$ in the traditional measure-theoretic manner (cf. [2] theorem 5.3.1, p. 205) as

> any solution, $\varphi$, to the integral system of equations
>    $$
>  \int_B \varphi\ dP_Y = P(X\in A, Y\in B),\hspace{1cm}B\text{ Borel}, \tag{*}\label{CondProb}
>  $$
>   where $P_Y$ is the distribution of $Y$, i.e. the probability measure induced on the Borel field via the formula $P_Y(E) = P(Y\in E)$.

(This concept of conditional probability is sometimes called "conditional distribution", as in [5] theorem 6.3, p. 107, and the term "conditional probability" is reserved to a closely-related, but different concept. I will keep to the "conditional probability" terminology.)

Given a two-dimensional random variable $(X,Y)$ with a joint density $f(x,y)$, we may now prove that the familiar definition of "conditional density", namely
$$
f_{X|Y=y}(x) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)},\hspace{1cm}\text{wherever the denominator does not vanish}
$$
can be used to generate conditional probabilities of the form $P(X\in A\ |\ Y=y)$.

Applying this technique to the following problem, taken from the same textbook ([6] example 5b, p. 252), we find that $P(X > 1\ |\ Y=y) = e^{-1/y}$, $y>0$.

> Suppose that the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is given by
>    $$
>  f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
> \frac{e^{-x/y}e^{-y}}{y} & 0 < x < \infty, 0 < y < \infty \\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
>  $$
>    Find $P(X > 1\ |\ Y=y)$.

Since the solution we obtained is continuous, Corollary 17(2) yields that, for every $y>0$,
$$
e^{-1/y} = \lim_{\Delta y\downarrow 0}\frac{P(X>1, y-\Delta y<Y<y+\Delta y)}{P(y-\Delta y<Y<y+\Delta y)}.
$$

---

***The formal derivation***

***Notation 1*** Let $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ and let $r \in (0,\infty)$. For every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we denote the open $n$-ball of (Euclidean) radius $r$ about $x$ by $B^{(n)}_r(x)$.

***Notation 2*** Let $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$. We denote the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $\mathcal{E}_n$.

***Notation 3*** Let $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$. We denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $\mathcal{B}_n$.

***Notation 4*** Let $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$. For every outer measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we denote the collection of $\mu$-measurable sets by $\mathcal{M}_\mu$.

Fix $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ for the remainder of the proof.

***Definition 5*** An outer measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is *Radon* iff the following three conditions hold.

1. $\mathcal{B}_n \subseteq \mathcal{M}_\mu$.
2. For every $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a $B\in\mathcal{B}_n$ such that $A\subseteq B$ and $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$.
3. For every $\mathcal{E}_n$-compact $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu(K) < \infty$.

***Definition 6*** Let $\mu, \nu$ be Radon outer measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We denote by $\mathrm{Diff}^\nu_\mu$ the set consisting of all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which the following pair of conditions hold.

1. For all $r \in (0,\infty)$, $\mu\left(B^{(n)}_r(x)\right) > 0$.
2. There exists some $d \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies:
   $$
    d = \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{\nu\left(B^{(n)}_r(x)\right)}{\mu\left(B^{(n)}_r(x)\right)}.
    $$

***Definition 7*** Let $\mu, \nu$ be Radon outer measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We set
 $$
 D^\nu_\mu(x) := \begin{cases}
 \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{\nu\left(B^{(n)}_r(x)\right)}{\mu\left(B^{(n)}_r(x)\right)} &, x \in \mathrm{Diff}^\nu_\mu \\
 0 &, \text{otherwise}.
 \end{cases}
 $$

***Definition 8*** Let $\mu, \nu$ be Radon outer measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We denote with $\mathrm{\mathbf{Diff}}^\nu_\mu$ the collection consisting of all $Z \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the following pair of conditions hold.

1. $Z \subseteq \mathrm{Diff}^\nu_\mu$.
2. $Z = \mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ for some $A \in \mathcal{M}_\mu$ with $\mu(A) = 0$.

***Theorem 9*** Let $\mu, \nu$ be Radon outer measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

1. $\mathrm{\mathbf{Diff}}^\nu_\mu \neq \emptyset$.
2. For every $Z \in \mathrm{\mathbf{Diff}}^\nu_\mu$, $D^\nu_\mu$ is $\mathcal{Z}/\mathcal{B}_1$-measurable, where $\mathcal{Z}$ is the subset $\sigma$-algebra induced on $Z$ by $\mathcal{M}_\mu$.

***Proof*** See [3], theorem 1.29, p. 48. Q.E.D.

***Definition 10***

1. Let $\mu, \nu$ be outer measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. $\nu$ is *absolutely continuous* w.r.t. $\mu$, written $\nu \ll \mu$, provided, $\mu(A) = 0$ implies $\nu(A) = 0$, for every $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.
2. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\mu, \nu$ be measures on $\mathcal{A}$. $\nu$ is *absolutely continuous* w.r.t. $\mu$, written $\nu \ll \mu$, provided, $\mu(A) = 0$ implies $\nu(A) = 0$, for every $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

***Lemma 11*** Let $\mu, \nu$ be measures on $\mathcal{B}_n$ such that $\nu\ll\mu$, and such that, for every $\mathcal{E}_n$-compact $K$, $\mu(K), \nu(K) < \infty$. Then $\mu, \nu$ can be extended to Radon outer-measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu^*, \nu^*$, respectively, such that $\nu^*\ll\mu^*$.

***Proof***

For every $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ define
$$
\begin{align}
\mu^*(A) &:= \inf \left\{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mu(B_n)\ :\!\big|\ \{B_1, B_2, \dots\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}_n,\ A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right\}, \\
\nu^*(A) &:= \inf \left\{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \nu(B_n)\ :\!\big|\ \{B_1, B_2, \dots\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}_n,\ A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right\}.
\end{align}
$$

According to [7] theorem 2.21 (p. 38), $\mu^*, \nu^*$ are outer-measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. According to [7] theorem 20.1(b) (p. 502), $\mu^*, \nu^*$ are extensions of $\mu, \nu$, respectively. This implies, in particular, that, for every $\mathcal{E}_n$-compact $K$, $\mu^*(K) = \mu(K) < \infty$. According to [7] theorem 20.1(a) (p. 502), $\mathcal{B}_n \subseteq \mathcal{M}_{\mu^*} \cap \mathcal{M}_{\nu^*}$. According to [7] Proposition 20.9 (p. 507), for every $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ there exist a $B \in \mathcal{B}_n$ such that $A \subseteq B$ and both $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(B)$ and $\nu^*(A) = \nu^*(B)$. Thus, $\mu^*$ and $\nu^*$ are each Radon.

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $\mu^*(A) = 0$. By the preceding paragraph there exists some $B \in \mathcal{B}_n$ such that $A \subseteq B$ and both $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(B)$ and $\nu^*(A) = \nu^*(B)$. So
$$
\mu(B) = \mu^*(B) = \mu^*(A) = 0.
$$
So
$$
\nu^*(A) = \nu^*(B) = \nu(B) \overset{\nu\ll\mu}{=} 0.
$$
Thus $\nu^* \ll \mu^*$.

Q.E.D.

***Theorem 12*** Let $\mu, \nu$ be Radon outer measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $Z \in \mathrm{\mathbf{Diff}}^\nu_\mu$. If $\nu \ll \mu$, then, for every $B \in \mathcal{M}_\mu$,
$$
\nu(B) = \int_B D^\nu_\mu\mathbb{1}_Z d\mu.
$$

***Proof*** See [3], theorem 1.30, p. 50. Q.E.D.

***Definition 13*** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, and let $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}_n$-measurable. We denote with $P_Y$ the probability measure induced on $\mathcal{B}_n$ by $Y$ via $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.

***Notation 14*** For every probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}_n$, we denote by $\overline{\mathcal{B}_n^\mu}$ the completion of $\mathcal{B}_n$ w.r.t. $\mu$, and we denote by $\overline{\mu}$ the unique extension of $\mu$ to $\overline{\mathcal{B}_n^\mu}$.

***Definition 15*** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, let $A \in \mathcal{F}$, and let $Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}_n$-measurable. We denote by $P(A\ |\ Y)$ the set of conditional probabilities of $A$ conditioned on $Y$, as follows. $P(A\ |\ Y)$ shall consist of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that are $\overline{\mathcal{B}_n^{P_Y}}/\mathcal{B}_1$-measurable, $\overline{P_Y}$-semi-integrable, and such that, for every $B \in \mathcal{B}_n$,
 $$
 \int_B f\ d\overline{P_Y} = P\left(A\cap\{Y \in B\}\right).
 $$

***Definition 16*** Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal{B}_n$. We denote $\mu$'s support by $\mathrm{supp}_\mu$. In other words, $\mathrm{supp}_\mu$ consists of all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that, for every $\mathcal{E}_n$-open-neighborhood, $G$, of $x$, $\mu(G) > 0$.

***Corollary 17*** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, let $A \in \mathcal{F}$, and let $Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}_n$-measurable. Set $\mu := P_Y$, and consider the measure $\nu:\mathcal{B}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ assigning to every $B \in \mathcal{B}_n$ $\nu(B) := P\left(A\cap\{Y \in B\}\right)$. Then $\mu, 
\nu$ can be extended to Radon outer-measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu^*, \nu^*$, respectively, such that:

1. $D^{\nu^*}_{\mu^*} \in P(A\ |\ Y)$.
2. For every $y \in \mathrm{supp}_\mu$ at which some $f \in P(A\ |\ Y)$ is $\mathcal{E}_n/\mathcal{E}_1$-continuous, $y \in \mathrm{Diff}^{\nu^*}_{\mu^*}$.

***Proof***

1. Since $\mu, \nu$ are finite measures on $\mathcal{B}_n$ such that $\nu \ll \mu$, then, by lemma 11, they may be extended to Radon outer-measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu^*, \nu^*$, respectively, such that $\nu^* \ll \mu^*$. Letting $Z \in \mathrm{\mathbf{Diff}}^{\nu^*}_{\mu^*}$, theorem 12 yields that $D^{\nu^*}_{\mu^*}\mathbb{1}_Z \in P(A\ |\ Y)$. Since, by choice of $Z$, $D^{\nu^*}_{\mu^*} = D^{\nu^*}_{\mu^*}\mathbb{1}_Z$ $P_Y$-a.e., the conclusion follows.
2. Let $y \in \mathrm{supp}_\mu$, and let $f \in P(A\ |\ Y)$ be $\mathcal{E}_n/\mathcal{E}_1$-continuous at $y$.

   Let $\varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$. Choose $\delta \in (0,\infty)$ such that, for all $z \in B^{(n)}_\delta(y)$, $f(z) \in B^{(1)}_\varepsilon\left(f(y)\right)$. Let $r \in (0,\delta]$. Since $y \in \mathrm{supp}_\mu$, $P_Y\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right) > 0$, and we have
   $$
    \begin{align}
    \frac{\nu^*\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)}{\mu^*\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)} &= \frac{\nu\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)}{\mu\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)} \\
    &= \frac{P\left(A\cap\left\{Y\in B^{(n)}_r(y)\right\}\right)}{P_Y\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)} \\
    &= \frac{\int_{B^{(n)}_r(y)}\ f\ d\overline{P_Y}}{P_Y\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)} \\
    &<\frac{\int_{B^{(n)}_r(y)}\ f(y) + \varepsilon\ d\overline{P_Y}}{P_Y\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)} \\
    &= \frac{(f(y)+\varepsilon)\ \int_{B^{(n)}_r(y)}\ d\overline{P_Y}}{P_Y\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)} \\
    &= (f(y)+\varepsilon)\frac{\overline{P_Y}\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)}{P_Y\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)} \\
    &= (f(y)+\varepsilon)\frac{P_Y\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)}{P_Y\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)} \\
    &= f(y)+\varepsilon.
    \end{align}
    $$

   Analogously,
   $$
    f(y)-\varepsilon < \frac{\nu^*\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)}{\mu^*\left(B^{(n)}_r(y)\right)}.
    $$

Q.E.D.

---

***References***

[1] Robert B. Ash, *Basic Probability Theory*, Dover, 2008. (An online version is freely available [on the author's website](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/BPT.html).)

[2] Robert B. Ash, Catherine A. Doléance-Dade, *Probability and Measure Theory*, 2nd ed., Academic Press, 2000.

[3] Lawrence C. Evans, Ronald F. Gariepy, *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions*, revised edition, CRC Press, 2015.

[4] William Feller, *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications*, Vol. 2, 2nd ed., John Wiley & Sons, 1971.

[5] Olav Kallenberg, *Foundations of Probability Theory*, 2nd ed., Springer, 2001.

[6] Sheldon M. Ross, *A First Course in Probability*, 9th ed., Pearson, 2013.

[7] James Yeh, *Real Analysis : Theory of Measure and Integration*, 3rd ed., World Scientific, 2014.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is more technical than what I can understand. Let me ask some question: I know generally $P(X \in A \vert f(X)=y)$ cannot be defined because of the zero event problem. But it can be defined under some condition. For example if the joint density of $X$ and $Y=f(X)$ exists, then $P(X \in A \vert f(X)=y)$ can be defined. Now my question is that, assume we don't know about the existence of the joint density function. But we know that function $f$ is measurable. Can we define $P(X \in A \vert f(X)=y)$ in this case?

Comment: @m0_as: I've added an appendix to my answer that describes a special case that you may find easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks. About the main question I asked, is the answer Yes? In the third paragraph, you say " Then it is a standard result that there exists a conditional probability $P(X \in A \vert Y=y)$." It seems to me that this is exactly what I wanted to know. Is there any reference for that?

Comment: @m0_as: Yes, I imagine that every book on measure-theoretic probability proves it. See, for instance, Theorem 5.3.1 on p. 205 of Ash & Doléance-Dade's "Probability & Measure Theory", 2nd ed. (Harcourt/Academic Press, 2000).

Comment: Is there any other reference which specifically talk about random variables $X$ and $Y$ and says that there exists a conditional probability $P(X \in A \vert Y=y)$?

Comment: @m0_as: I have rewritten my answer from scratch based on a new textbook I have come across today.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But, what I still don't get it is that in your example, you assume that the joint pdf exists and use that to derive the conditional probability. But, what if we don't know whether it exists or not?

Comment: @m0_as: From your comment it is clear that you have not read anything of what I wrote.

Comment: FYI, I share the puzzlement expressed by the OP in their last comment. So, you might want, first to climb down from your high horse, and second, to explain where in your answer are some elements that help to answer the question they asked. Unless I am mistaken, you only discuss examples where (X,Y) has a PDF, **which excludes the case Y=f(X)** that the OP is interested about.

Comment: Additionally, some inconvenient imprecisions seem to pop up as soon as you turn to concrete examples. For instance, when you declare "we start by defining the conditional probability $P(X\in A\ |\ Y=y)$ in the traditional measure-theoretic manner as any solution, $\varphi$, to the integral equation $\int_{\{X\in B\}} \varphi(X)\ dP = P(X\in A, Y\in B)$, $B\text{ Borel}$", I am sure the function $\varphi$ itself cannot be the conditional probability and I suspect that $\varphi(X)$ should read $\varphi(Y)$.

Comment: @Did: You are right about the $X$. Corrected. Regarding your previous comment. You are mistaken that I only discuss examples where $(X,Y)$ have PDF. The main result, Corollary 17, makes the following assumptions and nothing more: "Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, let $A \in \mathcal{F}$, and let $Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}_n$-measurable." With these assumptions alone it then goes on to address the conditional probability $P(A\ |\ Y)$. There is no reason why $A$ can't be $\{X\in E\}$ and $Y=f(X)$.

Comment: @Did: It is nowhere assumed that $(X,Y)$ has a pdf, and, to make the point even clearer, I added the example in the beginning where $(N,X)$ do not have a pdf, and I even wrote explicitly: "Note that in this example the joint random variable $(N,X)$ does not have a joint density".

Comment: @EvanAad I got your example now. In that example, instead of writing $P(N=n, X=x)$ which we don't know about the existence, it writes $P(N=n \vert X=x) f_X(x)$

Comment: In the example, the subscript $X\in B$ should still read $Y\in B$ and there is no way $P(X\in A\mid Y)$ can be defined as $\varphi$, you might mean $\varphi(Y)$. // So, in the end, which parts of this post *are* relevant? Not any paragraph where one assumes $(X,Y)$ has a PDF, anyway, so why include these? // My impression is that you are trying to build a theory you think was never exposed before (which is of course not so) instead of answering the precise question asked. Misuse of the site.

Comment: @Did: As I wrote in my post "I'll be grateful (if somewhat disappointed) to anyone who can cite a precedence." You claim that this theory is not new. Please cite a reference, and I'll be very grateful.

Comment: @Did: Thanks for the pointer about the $X\in B$ and the $\phi(Y)$. You are right, and I will correct it tomorrow when my head is clearer. I think everything in my post is relevant and that I answered the question that was asked.

Comment: @Did: Regarding the $\phi$ vs. $\phi(Y)$ issue. I think I made a mistake throughout the post by talking about conditional probability when I was actually thinking about conditional distribution, as defined [here](http://imgur.com/a/LFfWZ). I will correct this tomorrow when my thinking is clearer.

Comment: So, the limit exists if $\mathcal{N}$ is the Borel field, but it may not be exist for general $\mathcal{N}$? Or the result can be extended to general $\mathcal{N}$?

Comment: @m0_as: I don't know if the result can be extended to a general $\mathcal{N}$. The proof relies on the fact that $\mathcal{N}$ is the Borel field on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Can you specifically say why we can define conditional probability in this example "Consider $n+m$ trials having a common probability of success. Suppose, however, that this success probability is not fixed in advance but is chosen from a uniform $(0,1)$ population." I mean you say it is a direct result of Corollary 17. But, it is not clear to me.

Comment: @m0_as: Corollary 17(1) says the same thing as statement #2 at the beginning of my answer. I don't wish to answer any further questions concerning this post.