# A measure-theoretic analogue to the concept of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, reference-request, soft-question

Consider the following measure-theoretic analogy to the concept of derivative.

> Let $(\Omega, m)$ be a metric space ($\Omega\neq\emptyset$). Denote the topology on $\Omega$ induced by $m$ as $\tau$. Let $\mu, \nu$ be measures on $\sigma(\tau)$, and let $\omega^*\in\Omega$ belong to $\mu$'s support. Suppose the following holds. There is a number $d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that, for every sequence $(B_1, B_2, \dots)$ in $\sigma(\tau)$ consisting of $\tau$-neighborhoods of $\omega^*$, whose $m$-diameters converge to $0$,
>   $$
> d = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\nu(B_n)}{\mu(B_n)}.
> $$
>   Define $D^\nu_\mu(\omega^*):= d$.

Has this concept been studied? Does it have a name?

---

***How this concept comes about***

This concept arises naturally in the settings of conditional probability. For instance, in his textbook [Basic Probability Theory](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/BPT.html), Robert Ash writes: "A reasonable approach to the conditional probability $P(R_2 \in B\ |\ R_1 = x_0)$ is to look at $P(R_2 \in B\ |\ x_0-h< R_1 < x_0+h)$ and let $h\rightarrow 0$." (p. 136)

The limit
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow\infty} P(R_2 \in B\ |\ x_0-h< R_1 < x_0+h) = \lim_{h\rightarrow\infty}\frac{P(R_2 \in B, x_0-h< R_1 < x_0+h)}{P(x_0-h< R_1 < x_0+h)}
$$
can be restated (sort of) in the notation I introduced above as $D^\nu_\mu(x_0)$, where $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, $m$ is the Euclidean metric, $\mu = P_{R_1}$ (i.e. $\mu$ is $R_1$'s distribution), and $\nu$ is the measure that assigns to every Borel set $A$, $\nu(A) := P(R_2 \in B, R_1 \in A)$.

As a further evidence to how natural this intuitive view of conditional probability is, take [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938950/conditional-probability-on-zero-probability-events) posted yesterday on this forum, where a user who appears to be a beginning student of probability, is suggesting a definition of conditional probability essentially identical to Ash's "definition" above.

In my answer to said question I proved the following result, which I reformulate using the notation introduced above.

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and let $(S,m)$ be a metric space. Denote by $\tau$ the topology on $S$ induced by $m$. Let $Y:\Omega\rightarrow S$ be $\mathcal{F}/\sigma(\tau)$-measurable and let $A \in \mathcal{F}$.
>
> Denoting the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathcal{E}$, suppose that, for some version $f$ of the conditional probability $P(A\ |\ Y=y)$, $f$ is $\tau/\mathcal{E}$-continuous at some $y^*\in S$ that lies in $P_Y$'s support.
>
> Then
>   $$
> f(y^*) = D^\nu_\mu(y^*),\hspace{1cm}(*)
> $$
>   where $\mu := P_Y$, and $\nu$ is the measure on the Borel field on $\mathbb{R}$ that assigns to every Borel set $B$, $\nu(B):=P(A \cap \{Y\in B\})$. In particular, the expression on the right hand side of $(*)$ is well-defined.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the same as what you are describing above, but I know that in general treatments of Rademacher's theorem (all Lipschitz functions are almost everywhere differentiable) and Alexandrov's theorem (all convex functions are almost everywhere twice differentiable), discussions of measure-theoretic analogues/notions of derivative come up. I forgot the PDF's I skimmed through on the subject, but I think if you google the above theorems you will find survey articles discussing the theory behind their proofs in the most general case, which involve measure derivatives of some type.

Comment: @William: Thanks! It's a great start. If you happen to recall later specific articles, please let me know.

Comment: If $B_n$ are balls you recover the usual definition of derivative of a measure with respect to another. A reference could be *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* by Evans and Gariepy, where an entire section is called "differentiation of Radon measures". If you just require the diameter to go to zero I'm not sure...I think it is a very restrictive notion

Comment: @Del: Thanks. Sounds very promising. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Del: [I have used your reference to prove](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1938971/37058) that the conditional probability $P(A|Y=y)$ can be obtained almost surely as the limit $\lim_{\Delta y \downarrow 0} P\left(A|Y\in (y-\Delta y, y + \Delta y)\right)$. I can't thank you enough, as I've been wondering about this fact since the first time I took an introductory probability course as an undergraduate, and only now have I been able to prove it. I have never seen a proof of this fact in any textbook, so I'm kinda proud.

Comment: @EvanAad You're very welcome!