# Conditional probability on zero probability events (Application)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

This question can be regarded as an application to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938950/conditional-probability-on-zero-probability-events-definition).

Let $(\Omega ,{\mathcal {F}},P)$ be a probability space, $Z_1$ is a $(M_1,{\mathcal {M}_1})$-value random variable (that is it is $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{M}_1)$ measurable), $Z_2$ is a $(M_2,{\mathcal {M}}_2)$-value random variable,
$W$ is a $(N,{\mathcal {N}})$-value random variable, and $g$ is a measurable function. Assume that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent given any realization $w$ of $W$ (For example, $Z_1 = W + X_1$ and $Z_2 = W + X_2$ and $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent)

How can we use the definition to show that $P(Z_1 \in A_1, Z_2 \in A_2 \vert g(Z_1) \in B, W=w)
= P(Z_1 \in A_1 \vert g(Z_1) \in B, W=w)P(Z_2 \in A_2 \vert W=w)?$

This is quite intuitive that this should be true and I know that if $W$ is a discrete random variable, we can show the correctness of it using Bayes's rule. But, because of the fact that $P(W=w)$ can be zero, I don't know how to proceed in the general case.

**My solution:**
According to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938950/conditional-probability-on-zero-probability-events-definition), if $\mathcal{N}$ is a Borel sigma-algebra, and $g$ is Borel measurable, then:
\begin{align}
&P(Z_1 \in A_1, Z_2 \in A_2 \vert g(Z_1) \in B, W=w)= \\
&\lim_{r \mapsto 0} P(Z_1 \in A_1, Z_2 \in A_2 \vert g(Z_1) \in B, W \in (w-r,w+r)) = 
\\ 
&\lim_{r \mapsto 0} \dfrac{P(Z_1 \in A_1, Z_2 \in A_2, g(Z_1) \in B \vert W \in (w-r,w+r))}{P(g(Z_1) \in B \vert W \in (w-r,w+r))}
 = 
\\ 
&\lim_{r \mapsto 0} \dfrac{P(Z_1 \in A_1, g(Z_1) \in B \vert W \in (w-r,w+r))P(Z_2 \in A_2 \vert W \in (w-r,w+r))}{P(g(Z_1) \in B \vert W \in (w-r,w+r))}
 = \\
&\lim_{r \mapsto 0}  P(Z_1 \in A_1 \vert g(Z_1) \in B, W \in (w-r,w+r))P(Z_2 \in A_2 \vert W \in (w-r,w+r))= \\
& P(Z_1 \in A_1 \vert g(Z_1) \in B, W=w)P(Z_2 \in A_2 \vert W=w).
\end{align}
Is this correct if $\mathcal{N}$ is a Borel sigma-algebra, and $g$ is Borel measurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a short and sweet derivation of the equation you are interested in, followed by a detailed explanation.

$$
\begin{align}
P\left(Z_1 \in A_1, Z_2 \in A_2\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}},\ W\right)
&= E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}}, W\right) \\
&= E\left(E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ Z_1, W\right)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}}, W\right)\\
&= E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\ E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ Z_1, W\right)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}}, W\right)\\
&= E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\ E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ W\right)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}}, W\right)\\
&= E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}}, W\right) E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ W\right)\\
&= P\left(Z_1 \in A_1\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}}, W\right) P\left(Z_2 \in A_2\ |\ W\right).
\end{align}
$$

---

OK, so regarding [that question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938950/conditional-probability-on-zero-probability-events-definition?noredirect=1#comment3991071_1938950), the most important thing for you to take from [my answer to it](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1938971/37058) is not the formula
$$
P(X\in A\ |\ Y=y) = \lim_{\Delta y\downarrow 0}\frac{P\left(X\in A,\ y-\Delta y < Y < y+\Delta y\right)}{P\left(y-\Delta y < Y < y+\Delta y\right)},
$$
but rather what I stated in the beginning as fact #2:

> the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ obtained by setting $f(y) := \lim_{\Delta y \mapsto 0} P(X \in A\ |\ Y \in (y-\Delta y, y+\Delta y))$ wherever possible, and, say, $f(y):=0$ elsewhere, is consistent with the traditional measure-theoretic definition of $P(X\in A\ |\ Y=y)$.

This means that, even though the traditional measure-theoretic definition of conditional probability is inscrutable, you can rest assured that it is the same thing as the intuitive limit-oriented definition that you proposed, at least as long as the conditioning variables (i.e. the ones on the right hand side of the $|$ symbol) take values in the Borel space $\mathbb{R}^n$. If they don't, the definitions may or may not coincide, I simply don't know at the present time, but I wouldn't bet a large sum of money on it.

A compelling reason to use the traditional definition is that there are a whole bunch of useful facts that were discovered about it, and we can use these facts out-of-the box to help us figure out complex problems involving conditional probabilities, like the one you posed in your question, and write short and sweet proofs, like the one I opened this answer with.

In fact, there are so many useful facts such as these, that you can often use them to prove stuff about conditional probabilities without once referring to the definition of conditional probability, which is awesome, because the definition is complicated, but many of the facts are easy to state and remember. As a case in point, in this answer I'm not going to use the definition once; just various facts about it.

Another important, but delicate, point to note, before we delve into answering your question, is that the expression $P(X\in A\ |\ Y=y)$ is not technically a conditional *probability*, but rather a conditional *distribution*, evaluated at $A$. The difference between a conditional probability and a conditional distribution is that a conditional distribution is a function over $Y$'s *range*, whereas a conditional probability is a function over $Y$'s *domain*. So, if $Y$ is a random variable on the measurable space $\Omega$ that takes values in the measurable space $E$, then a conditional distribution is a function of the form
$$
y_{\in E} \mapsto P(A\ |\ Y=y),
$$
whereas a conditional probability is a function of the form
$$
\omega_{\in\Omega} \mapsto P(A\ |\ Y)(\omega).
$$
We don't usually specify the $\omega$ when dealing with conditional *probabilities*; we simply write $P(A\ |\ Y)$.

There is a very simple relation between the conditional distribution $P(A\ |\ Y=y)$ and the corresponding conditional probability $P(A\ |\ Y)$. Writing $f(y):=P(A\ |\ Y=y)$, the relation is
$$
P(A\ |\ Y) = f(Y).
$$

It is very easy to translate any statement that is couched in the language of conditional distributions to an equivalent statement about conditional probabilities: formally, it is just a matter of dropping the argument "y", so: $P(A\ |\ Y=y)$ (a conditional distribution) becomes $P(A\ |\ Y)$ (a conditional probability). All the useful facts that I mentioned above are stated in terms of conditional *probabilities*, so we want to make sure we translate any problem involving conditional distributions to one involving conditional probabilities before we start shifting the pieces around.

So, finally, let's address your question. The first tricky thing to deal with is that the expression
$$
P(Z_1 \in A_1, Z_2 \in A_2 \vert g(Z_1) \in B, W=w)
$$
doesn't look like either a conditional probability or a conditional distribution, since the conditioning part consists of an event, $\{g(Z_1) \in B\}$ as well as of a random variable $W$, and when we deal with conditional probabilities, we want the conditioned part to be homogeneous: either all events, or all random variables. In the former case, we're in the realm of discrete probability. In the latter case, we're in the realm of general (i.e., measure-theoretic) probability.

Fortunately for us, there's nothing easier than rephrasing an event, $A$, in terms of a random variable. Just write
$$
A = \{\mathbb{1}_A = 1\},
$$
where $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the indicator function of the event $A$ w.r.t. the sample space $\Omega$.

So first thing we rewrite the expression
$$
P(Z_1 \in A_1, Z_2 \in A_2 \vert g(Z_1) \in B, W=w)
$$
as
$$
P\left(Z_1 \in A_1, Z_2 \in A_2\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}}=1,\ W=w\right).
$$
Now that we have an expression that looks like a conditional *distribution*, we drop the arguments on the right hand side of the $|$ symbol, to obtain the conditional *probability*
$$
P\left(Z_1 \in A_1, Z_2 \in A_2\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}},\ W\right).
$$
We do the same with the other expressions appearing in the equation we wish to prove, to obtain
$$
P\left(Z_1 \in A_1, Z_2 \in A_2\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}},\ W\right) = P\left(Z_1 \in A_1\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}}, W\right) P\left(Z_2 \in A_2\ |\ W\right).
$$
*This* is what we are going to prove. Incidentally, when dealing with conditional probabilities, every "$=$" sign must be understood as "$=$ almost surely".

Now, remember I said that there are a whole bunch of facts about conditional probabilities that we can use to write proofs succinctly and elegantly? I lied! Actually, all these facts are about conditional *expectations*, so, if we want to be able to tap into this cornucopia of facts, we need to rewrite the problem in terms of conditional expectations. How do we do it? Easy-peasy! Remember that, for every event $A$, we have
$$
P(A) = E(\mathbb{1}_A)?
$$
(if you don't remember, try to prove it. It's a discrete probability fact, and you're an expert in discrete probability if you've reached this far in your studies.)
The analogous equality involving conditionals is valid too:
$$
P(A\ |\ Y) = E(\mathbb{1}_A\ |\ Y).
$$
Just take my word for it, as you must take my word for all the other facts involving conditional expectation that I'm about to use. But write down all these facts, so you can use them later in other problems. In fact, why bother writing them down, when there's [an entire Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) listing all the most useful properties of conditional expectations. We will refer to this list in what follows.

An important consequence of the last equation, one which we will have occasion to refer to later, is that $E(\mathbb{1}_A\ |\ Y)$ is a function of $Y$. Why? Because $P(A\ |\ Y)$ is a function of $Y$. Why? Because, as we mentioned above, $P(A\ |\ Y) = f(Y)$ where $f$ is the conditional distribution $P(A\ |\ Y=y)$. It is possible to generalize the fact that $E(\mathbb{1}_A\ |\ Y)$ is a function of $Y$ to show that $E(X\ |\ Y)$ is a function of $Y$ for any random variable $X$. (Again, you'll have to trust me on this.) Remember this fact! We will use it in the very last step of the solution to your question.

Now that we've spent all this time talking about conditional distributions, I'd like to come clean, that I haven't used this terminology quite precisely. When professional mathematicians talk about conditional distributions, they mean something a little different to the concept I dubbed as such above. But I needed a word to distinguish between $P(A\ |\ Y=y)$ as a function on $Y$'s range, and $P(A\ |\ Y)$ as a function on $Y$'s domain, and "conditional distribution" seemed good enough. I'm not aware of any standard terminology to facilitate distinguishing between these concepts.

Alright, so now that we've transformed all the conditional probabilities into conditional expectations, we're down to proving the following claim:
$$
E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}}, W\right) = E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_{\{g(Z_1) \in B\}}, W\right) E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ W\right).
$$
(Again, the equation is only true almost surely, but you've already got that, right? So from now on I won't point this out every time. Just keep it in the back of your mind.)

Here's the rest of the proof. I'll write it down in one fell swoop and then go back and explain every step. Setting $D:=g^{-1}(B)$, so that $\{g(Z_1) \in B\} = \{Z_1 \in D\}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_D(Z_1), W\right) &= E\left(E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ Z_1, W\right)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_D(Z_1), W\right) \tag{1}\\
&= E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\ E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ Z_1, W\right)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_D(Z_1), W\right) \tag{2}\\
&= E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\ E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ W\right)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_D(Z_1), W\right) \tag{3}\\
&= E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(Z_1)\ |\ \mathbb{1}_D(Z_1), W\right) E\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)\ |\ W\right). \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Referring to the Wikipedia list,

- equation 1 is due to the tower property, since $(\mathbb{1}_D(Z_1), W)$ is a function of $(Z_1, W)$,
- equations 2 is due to the "pulling out known factors" property,
- equation 3 is due to Doob's conditional independence property, seeing as it was stated in your question that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ were independent given $W$.
- equations 4 is again due to the "pulling out known factors" property, since $E(\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(Z_2)|W)$ is a function of $W$. (Remember we promised we'd use this fact in the last step of the proof? We've come through.)

... and we're done!

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your comprehensive response. I learnt new things by reading it. After converting the original problem to the one in term of conditional probability, I got the way you proved it and it is correct. The only question remaining for me now is that how we translate back what we proved to the form of original problem? What you showed is true almost surely. So, does it mean as follows? If the conditional probabilities of the original problem can be defined, the equality holds.

Comment: And if we assume the Borel measurability whenever needed, then the conditional probabilities of the original problem can be defined (according to your solution to the other question I asked). So, the equality of the original holds. Right?

Comment: @m0_as: "how we translate back what we proved to the form of original problem?" You translate it back by transforming the conditional expectations back to conditional probabilities, and then pushing in the arguments back on the right hand side of the $|$ sign. This is justified as long as the variables on the *left* hand side of the $|$ take values in the Borel field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or indeed in any topological Borel field -- [see here](http://imgur.com/a/LFfWZ)).For example, cond. exp. $E(1_{A_2}(Z_2)|W)$ becomes cond. prob. $P(Z_2\in A_2|W)$, which becomes cond. dist. $P(Z_2\in A_2|W=w)$.

Comment: @m0_as: "does it mean as follows? If the conditional probabilities of the original problem can be defined, the equality holds" No, it means that, within the set of points where the original conditional distributions can be defined in terms of the limiting procedure, the equality holds almost everywhere, but not everywhere. However, it can be inferred from Corollary 17(2) of my answer to your previous question that if all three conditional distributions are continuous in some open neighborhood, then equality holds between the two sides of the equation everywhere in that neighborhood.

Comment: @m0_as: In probability theory equality of functions is almost never of interest, and, at any rate, can almost never be guaranteed. The strongest form of equality you can hope for is equality almost surely.

Comment: I see. So according to what you said " it means that, within the set of points where the original conditional distributions can be defined in terms of the limiting procedure, the equality holds almost everywhere, but not everywhere", what you proved is weaker than what we have in the original problem because the original problem says that they are equal "not only almost everywhere", but also "everywhere" because it says it is true for any realization irrespective of its probability.

Comment: @m0_as: Just like the equality sign in probability often means merely equality almost everywhere, so should the quantifier "for all"/"for any" often be interpreted in this weaker light. This is known as a "sociomathematical norm". In other words, it is a commonly understood convention that mathematicians working in the field of probability use, to make sentences less cumbersome, and to save a few key strokes. Since the modifier "almost everywhere" is so ubiquitous in probability, you can see what a pain it is to repeat it all the time. So it is commonly agreed to leave it unexpressed,

Comment: So you mean the original problem should also be read as an equality in almost-sure sense and not everywhere?

Comment: @m0_as: Exactly.

Comment: @m0_as: I'd like to correct one of my comments above. When I explained how to translate a conditional probability back to a conditional distribution I wrote that this technique was justified as long as the conditioned variables take values in a Borel field. However, the restriction to a Borel field isn't necessary when dealing with conditional probabilities of the form $P(A|Y)$, where $A$ is a fixed event, as in your current post. When $A$ is fixed, there is always a corresponding "distribution" $P(A|Y=y)$, though the word may be misleading in this case, but I'm not aware of a better one.

Comment: Just for clarification, the fact you mentioned that  "as long as the conditioned variables take values in a Borel field" is for which step? for going to conditional expectation to conditional probability or from conditional probability to corresponding "distribution"? I got confused.

Comment: @m0_as: The point is there are no constraints to worry about when performing this procedure in either direction. So don't worry about it.